# A clock takes 6 seconds to strike 4 times at 4:00. How many seconds will it take to strike 6 times at 6:00?

Tags: arithmetic

This is an exercise from a child's elementary school homework.

```
A clock takes 6 seconds to strike 4 times at 4:00.
How many seconds will it take to strike 6 times at 6:00?
```

My logic:

```
6 seconds/4 strikes = 1.5 second/strike.
1.5 seconds/strike x 6 strikes = 9 seconds.
```

The author says the answer is **10 seconds**.

In the workbook the student is not yet introduced to fractions, so I assume there is 
another way to solve this.

Comment: Hint: it seems the workbook is counting from after the first chime ends to the end of the last chime.

Comment: A somewhat similar question is at:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479029/seconds-of-a-clock?noredirect=1#comment3011689_1479029

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let a dash `-` represent one second. If a clock takes 6 seconds to strike 4 times, then it strikes this pattern:

`bong--bong--bong--bong`

Continue the pattern to strike 6 times:

`bong--bong--bong--bong--bong--bong`

Upon counting, there are 10 dashes!

That said, the question is somewhat ambiguous. One suspects that it's an intentional trap, luring the student into a mistake so that they can be taught about [fencepost errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

Answer (score 6):

$4$ strikes means there are $3$ intervals between them so $\frac{6}{3}=2$ seconds each (if the strike itself does not take any time).

$6$ strikes means there are $5$ intervals between them so $5\cdot2=10$ seconds in total.

You are correct. No fractions.:)

Answer (score 1):

The first bong is striked at exactly $4:00$ pm. The next 3 in the next 6 seconds. 
So, that 2 seconds per strike.

Again, to strike 6, the first one will go off at exactly $6:00$ pm followed by another 5 strikes, so that's $5\times2=10$ seconds.

Now this is because, if the clock were to strike 4 bongs in 6 seconds, then it should have started at $3:59:54$, so by the time it reaches 4:00 it is complete. **But this does not happen**, as it will increase the need of calibration in clocks.