# The first thought for this puzzle is wrong but it is also one that seems most natural. What is the correct comparable approach?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, logic, puzzle, average

There is the puzzle that given the information that:

> a clock at 6 o'clock struck 6 times and the time elapsed between the
> first and last strike was 30 seconds asks how long will it take to
> strike 12 times at noon.

The first and intuitive thought is to use average i.e. 30/6 * 12 = 60 seconds. But that is wrong.
Although I do know the answer, which is that we need to distinguish between the strikes and the breaks I am not sure how to formalize it in the sense with what is this comparable that we are familiar with.
I mean if we were given instead of clock strikes e.g. prepare cakes I think the first thought again would be the average per cake but I am trying to understand where the fallacy comes from and what is the formal way to remove it (with something else we are familiar).

**Update:**
In regards to the prepare cakes example that confused people. What I meant was that following 2 puzzles are directly equivalent:

> a clock at 6 o'clock struck 6 times and the time elapsed between the
> first and last strike was 30 seconds asks how long will it take to
> strike 12 times at noon.

> a cake is hand out to a customer/waiter at min 0 and the 6th cake is handed out in min 30. How long will it take to hand out 12 cakes?

What I had in mind is that there seems to me that there is a more general process that is directly there for both clock/cake puzzle and as a result we would make the same fallacy i.e. for the cakes 30/6 * 12 = 60 mins which should be wrong since again the preparing of the cake (which is the equivalent of the break between strikes) is still not taken into account.

Of course I might be confused completely and would be glad if my confusion was cleared by someone

Comment: In one case, the clock, you're asked for the number of boundary points of the interval, and in the other, for the number of intervals.  It the difference between the number of fenceposts and intervals between the posts.

Comment: A popular puzzle. It takes 30 s for *the five intervals between the six strikes*.

Comment: @saulspatz: Could you elaborate please on this? Isn't the question always about the interval given different strikes/fenceposts?

Comment: Not the question about the cakes, if I understand it right.

Comment: @saulspatz: I mentioned the cakes because they seem comparable and the same falacy can happen in both cases.

Comment: This puzzle seems great, though the only possible thing I can think of in this situation is that the interval of each strike would be 5 seconds, though I'm not sure if its right.

Comment: You'll have to state the problem with the cakes explicitly.  I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @saulspatz: May be I using a wrong example but I think that the puzzle is at fist confusing and the natural thought is to use average (like when a car travels a distance) and that I thought that this "fallacy" i.e. the natural thought to average, would occur in the general form of the puzzle which would be for any distinct process either it is clock strikes or prepare cakes (e.g. it takes 30 mins from the 1st cake that was delivered to the 6th hence 30/6*12 for the 12 cakes but again it leaves out the cake preparation time) etc

Comment: You're critiquing the solution to a problem you haven't stated.  I still don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: Still don't understand what "prepare cakes" are supposed to do.

Comment: @MarkGiraffe: Please see updated OP

Comment: @saulspatz: Please see updated OP. Does that help/clarify?

Comment: Okay. Never heard of this riddle before, although it still remains consistent that the interval of clock strikes would be 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the same problem, but notice that it says nothing about the time to prepare the cakes, which is what your post talks about above.  It's essentially the mistake  of saying that the number of integers from $a$ to $b$ is $b-a$ instead of $b-a+1$.  This is so common in computer programming that it has a name: "off-by-one error" (latterly, "Obi-wan error.")

Comment: @saulspatz: So what I am trying to understand is what would be a general version of the puzzle be and what are the components that show that it is different reasoning process than e.g the physics velocity example that we average for speed.

Comment: @Jim Is it 66sec the answer?

Comment: @Raffaele: Yes it is 66 seconds *provided* that the time required for a strike = 0

Comment: @Jim Not really. For the 6 struck at 6.00 it takes 30 sec *including* the time for the strikes. Thus we can assume that at 12.00 the time up to the 11th strike is 60 sec plus the time waiting for the 12th, 5.45 sec goes near 66 sec

Comment: @Raffaele: If we assume that the time for a strike takes 0 seconds then the time till the 12th strike is 6*11 = 66 (since we have 11 intervals).

Comment: @saulspatz: Did the original post improve? From you first comment I think you got my question, since that distinction with the fencepost starting to shed light. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: I really don't have any more to say on this subject.

Comment: This puzzle uses the assumption that each strike takes a total of 0 seconds, or that the time between the START of each strike is 6 seconds.